# Install PHP Imagick

Tags: php, windows, imagemagick, php-7.1

I downloaded the zip from this [link](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.3/php_imagick-3.4.3-7.1-ts-vc14-x86.zip) and copied **php_imagick.dll** file to **ext** directory on my windows pc (attachment1.png).
[image: attachment1.png]

But when i open **cmd** and type **php -v**, I get this warning(attachment2.png). I even tried the NTS and x64 versions as well but with no luck.
[image: attachment2.png]

Here's my image magick details.[image: imagemagick.png]

Somebody help please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes libraries fail to load with that message and the real problem is that the library can't be loaded because of *another* missing library that they need.

The `vc14` in the zip that you downloaded means that version of ImageMagick was compiled with Visual Studio 2015, so it require the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685) for 32 bits (x86) for working, check that you have it installed (note that there are versions for 32 and 64 bit, you need the 32 bit version in this case, you can have both versions installed if needed).